# Different results during Debug and Run in C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm working on a algorithm problem, and it discribed as follows:

> Suppose the deep learning model is a directed acyclic graph. If operator A depends on the output of operator B, then A can be calculated after the execution of B. If there is no dependency relation, then A can be executed in parallel. Given N nodes, the information of each node contains the execution time of the node and the list of the next nodes, and the shortest execution time of the neural network is calculated. **The node index starts at 0.**

and here is the input example:

```
7
A 10 1 2 3
B 9 4 5 6
C 22
D 20
E 19
F 18
G 21
```

Here is my solution:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int dfs(int nodeTime, const vector<int>& nextNodes, vector<vector<int>> NN){
    // Check whether the children of the current node have children
    bool is_end = true;
    for (int node : nextNodes) {
        if (NN[node][1] != 0){
            is_end = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    //The children of the current node have no children, find the maxTime
    if (is_end) {
        int maxTime = 0;
        for (int node : nextNodes) {
            maxTime = max(node, maxTime);
        }
        return nodeTime + maxTime;
    }

    //some children of the current node have children, keep doing dfs()
    else{
        int maxTime = 0;
        for (int nodeIdx : nextNodes) {
            if (NN[nodeIdx].size() != 1){
                vector<int> next;
                next.assign(NN[nodeIdx].begin() + 1, NN[nodeIdx].end());
                maxTime = max(maxTime, dfs(NN[nodeIdx][0], next, NN));
            }
            else maxTime = max(maxTime, NN[nodeIdx][0]);
        }
        return maxTime + nodeTime;
    }
}

int str_int(const string& s){
    char c[10];
    strcpy(c, s.c_str());
    return atoi(c);
}

int main() {
    // input stage
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> NN;
    vector<int> temp;
    vector<string> stemp;
    string s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        stemp.clear();
        temp.clear();
        while (cin >> s){
            stemp.push_back(s);
            if (getchar() == '\n') break;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < stemp.size(); ++j) {
            temp.push_back(str_int(stemp[j]));
        }
        NN.push_back(temp);
    }

   
    vector<int> initialNextNodes; //Initialize the sequence of children of the starting node
    initialNextNodes.assign(NN[0].begin() + 1, NN[0].end());
    int res = dfs(NN[0][0], initialNextNodes, NN);
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

The right output is `40`, Debug mode gives the right answer, but Run mode gives the wrong answer, I can't figure out what went wrong. I looked up the common causes of this error, probably a pointer being used without space allocated, or a variable being used without an initial value assigned. But these do not seem to be the answer to my question, can anyone help me? I would be so grateful.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) And [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: And different behavior between a "debug" and a "release" build (or similar concepts), typically indicated *undefined behavior*. Add lots of debug output to see values of variables and calculations at different times in the program.

Comment: Code that changes behaviour (in your case, observable output) when compiled with different optimisation settings (e.g. "Debug" versus "Release") is often a hint to the presence of undefined behaviour.   With more aggressive optimisation, the compiler takes more liberties in reorganising the code, and that increases likelihood of symptoms.   Stepping through with a debugger won't necessarily work to isolate the problem - try adding bounds checking everywhere in your code (particularly array indices) you can.

Comment: Start by enabling as many compiler warnings as you can (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror` is a good *start* with `g++`). Then *fix* all the warnings. Then enable undefined behaviour sanitizer and fix what it finds. Then try enabling address sanitizer and fix what it finds. You can also try running `clang-tidy` over your code and fix what it points out.

Comment: This is due to a bug in the shown code from an out of bounds array access. If you replace ***every*** occurence of the subscript operator, `[]`, with `at()`, an exception will be thrown, and you can figure out the bug all by yourself.

Comment: A difference between Debug Mode and Release Mode should be expected, especially execution times.  Verify the optimization settings for the Release Mode.